# Problems getting OpenGL to work in VSCode on Mac

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, glfw, glad

I am trying to complie a basic openGL program in VSCode on mac. I am using glad and GLFW, and I have the Glad files in the same folder as the test.cpp file I am trying to run. However, the include statement throws an error no matter how I type it. This is the program I am writing

```cpp
#include <iostream>  
#include "glad.h"
```

However, it throws the errors:
[screenshot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyk5s.png)

VSCode cannot find the header files the program needs to run, and the compiler throws errors as a result. I should add, that autocomplete for these libraries is working, however, the file cannot be found by the editor.

Here is the c_cpp_properties.json code

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Perhaps the problem could be realted to how I am trying to compile the file? Here is my tasks.json file

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",

            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Any guidance on how to set this project up correctly, any advice would be greatly appreciated. For reference, here is the tutorial I am trying to follow: https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Window.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please do not post images of errors, instead post text compiler output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start by pointing out a few things that aren't really important.

VSCode is not a compiler, nor an IDE. VScode is a **text editor.** As a text editor it may have some extensions that help you with developing (thus turning it into a make-shift IDE).

What is happening here is that the compiler (gcc) doesn't know where to look for include files. It is even hinting you that you need to update the `includePath` in a way that you point it to the correct folder with the header files. In the CLI this is done via the `-I` flag i.e. `g++ main.cpp -Ipath/to/your/include_folder/`.

If you look into the [Getting Started section](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Creating-a-window) they even go through these steps and go as far as to suggest the usage of `CMake` (which is a build tool that helps you generate the makefile with which you build your binaries).

By looking at the `tasks.json` I can conclude that the extension which you are using in VSCode uses this file to pass down the correct arguments to `g++`. So the quickest solution for you right now is to specify another element in `args` that points to the header files i.e.:

```
"args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "-Ipath/to/your/include_folder/with_the_headers", <----
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",

        ],
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That is incredibly helpful, I was having a hard time wrapping my head around how to pass the compiler the needed information. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help and good luck with your endeavours:)